# How to remove save username and password in composer (laravel 4)

Tags: php, terminal, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have updated my laravel vendor using composer. I have bought a package which is located in a github private repo. On downloading composer ask username and password, I have entered the wrong password so it gives me an error. After that I run composer update again but this time it just keep the old wrong password it did not ask me to enter the password again, somewhat save in composer cache. How could I remove the old password in composer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your `~/.composer`, you'll have a file named `config.json` which contains OAuth token used to log you in GitHub.

Clear your OAuth token or delete this file.

Answer (score 18):

Mine was in `~/.config/composer` in there is a `auth.json` that contains saved credentials.  Like netvision73 answer, clear your OAuth token or delete the file.

Answer (score 5):

I had only clear the cache
`composer clear-cache`

Answer (score 0):

In my case deleting `~/.composer/cache` and `~/.composer/auth.json` worked (my app is deployed inside docker container)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

For me updating the `~/.composer/auth.json` with the correct username and password worked.

1. updated the `~/.composer/auth.json` with correct username and password.
2. tried installing the package again.

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights. If this is the case here, please add more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase this is not a duplicate answer, no other comments are talking about updating the `~/.composer/auth.json` file.

Comment: Are you sure? The answer from gettmure is talking about exactly that file, the answer from Xenocide8998 mentions that file at another location. If you think your answer is different, please add some more explanation to it such that others can learn from it