# Composer: "Warning: You should avoid overwriting already defined auth settings" after changing authentication settings?

Tags: php, linux, git, composer-php

I have some git repositories where the authentication method changed (from OAuth to HTTP) so I had to change the authentication details in my Composer project.

I opened up `auth.json` and `composer.lock` and replaced all references to the old authentication details with the new ones (simple username/password).

Now when I run `composer update` I receive the following warning:

> Warning: You should avoid overwriting already defined auth settings for example.com

I have tried `composer clearcache` etc. but the message always remains and it's very annoying.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

About the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/http-basic-authentication.md)... maybe saved in your `auth.json`. But it is just my tip.
I found another similar question what is useful for you: [How to remove save username and password in composer (laravel 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416486/how-to-remove-save-username-and-password-in-composer-laravel-4)